# Microsoft Identity platform Configure dependencies never finish

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I tried to add Microsoft Identity platform to a MVC project in Visual Studio 2019, on Connected Services page, I clicked on Configure next to Microsoft identity platform, then followed the steps:

1. chose my Azure tenant (b2c)(I am a admin)
2. chose / create an new app registration
3. on summary of changes, it said : project changes for dependencies being added or configured:
4. click finished, the Dependency configuration progress windows showed nothing and stayed open even checked "Automatically close when succeeded",

after sometime, nothing happened, then I canceled it and returned back to Connected Service page, the Microsoft identity platform still show "**Configure**" icon, not **configured** like other option (secrets.json(local) which configured in few seconds)

I have tried different projects types, also tried to download a sample project, still the same, am I missing any updates/components/libraries? please advice, thank you very much

Comment: Have you ever found an answer? I am stuck at the same point.

Comment: Did you try `msidentity-app-sync` command as explained in option 2 of https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/tools/app-provisioning-tool/vs2019-16.9-how-to-use.md ?

I recently tried for blazor web assembly (hosted with .NET server) app, using command `msidentity-app-sync --tenant-id <tenantIdFromYourAzureAD>`, it automatically created app registration and also updated corresponding app setting json files and program file.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck here too. Tried again and clicked "Finish" instead of Next and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).